# Objects with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm a bit new with Javascript and I'm trying to create objects with arrays inside.
In C I have sort it out easily using structs, but in Javascript I'm a little bit lost. Here's my code:

```
function Switch() {
  var title;
  var toggleModeEnable;
};

function Layer () {
  sw = [8];
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      sw[j] = new Switch();
  };
};

var lr = [10];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    lr[i] = new Layer();
};
```

Obviously, this doesn't work.
What I'm trying to achieve is having an array (lr) of 10 elements. Each of them should be an ayyay of 8 elements (sw), and each one with two properties (title and toggleModeEnable), and access them with something like this:

```
lr[1].sw[3].title
```

But something like this throws an error like:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined at :1:9"

What I'm missing here?

Comment: When you write `[10]` you are creating an array with one value, the number 10. Array lengths can change dynamically so you can just leave it empty and add each element as needed with `.push(new Layer())`

Comment: And the same for your other array instantiation

Comment: Whatever book you're using to learn about JavaScript object construction is doing a really bad job. You need `title` and `toggleModeEnable` and `sw` to be instance properties of the corresponding objects, not local variables.

Comment: Hi @Alvaro. Please don't post an answer to thank anyone, (if it's not here, it's probably already been removed), that should be a comment instead. Answers should answer the question. Also, if an answer resolved all your questions, I'd suggest [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/544203), to show your appreciation, and so others who view this question will know it worked.

Comment: Sorry, new here. Got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```js
function Switch() {
  this.title = '';
  this.toggleModeEnable = false;
}

function Layer () {
  this.sw = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    this.sw.push(new Switch());
  }
}

const lr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  lr.push(new Layer());
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I'm trying the first one, which looks more familiar to me, and it's working now. Although other answers are very instructive too!

Awesome community.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you should take into account.

- *Firstly*, variables should be defined using `let` or `const`, not `var`. Using `var` to define variables can cause problems in `"use strict"` mode, as stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
- *Secondly*, functions should return something.
- *Thirdly*, neither the `Switch` nor the `Layer` functions take arguments, so they'll return the same values.
- *Fourthly*, as they are functions, you shouldn't use `new` unless they have been defined as objects – you just call the function.
- *Finally*, as the objects stored on the arrays have no key names, you only need to use `lr[0][0]` to get the first value from the first object in the array.

So, taking all that into account, try this:

```js
function Layer (i) {

  function Switch(j) {
    let title = "aaa." + i + "." + j;
    let toggleModeEnable = false;
    return {title, toggleModeEnable};
  };

  let sw = [8];
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    sw[j] = Switch(j);
   };
   
   return sw;
};

let lr = [10];
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    lr[i] = Layer(i);
};

console.log(lr[1][3]);
console.log(lr[1][6]);
```

Comment: Okay, if variables aren't defined using `var`, then (1) why are you using var in your code, and (2) what is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)?

Comment: But variables *can* be defined with `var`. Why are you saying they can't? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: var can be used but can cause problems in "use strict" mode - as that link points out.  I've never used var (except when I've forgotten what I'm coding in).  And, for someone relatively new to javascript, getting errors about variables declared using var can be confusing.

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. You should state that, because it can be more confusing to wonder why `var` can't be used (your answer seems to imply that it's not valid JS), when it *can*, but just it might cause problems. I'm not relatively new to Javascript and I was confused, so...

Comment: Sorry, yes, perhaps I should have - I just find it easy to show someone a snippet of code that won't have problems just because of how something is defined!  I rarely use "use strict" but I would much rather code in a way that will work regardless of the mode.  I never teach anyone to use "var" probably because I've never used it in javascript and always think of it as a variable declaration in other coding environments!

Answer (score 0):

you can add parameters to make the structure more flexible.

```
const test = LR(10);
console.log(test);
function LR(length){
    const lr=[];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
      lr.push(LAYER(8));
      return lr;
   }
}

function SWITCH(title){
  return {
    title:title,
    toggleModeEnable:false
  }
}
function LAYER(size){
  const sw=[];
   for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    sw.push(SWITCH(""));
  }
  return sw;
}
```